# Calendar + Custom Table + Add views from template

Tags: views, datetime

My custom table has 5 datetime columns.

I am able to create Calendar view using 3 of those columns but 2 of those columns are not listed in "Add view from template" list.

I have no idea why [Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) module is leaving these 2 columns out from "Add view from template" list. Any thoughts ?